# Angular dynamic set content and link

Tags: angular

i would like to be able to build my angular project one time and use it in different path without need to ricompile it

for example :

A project has index.html and api path

and changing something at runtime make it works in two or more different path

mysite/A  ->  mysite/A/index.html  and mysite/A/api
mysite/B  ->  mysite/B/index.html  and mysite/B/api

I would like to deploy my code into a container and reuse same image for different environment.angu

Comment: change baseHref in the index.html

Comment: it doesn't work with generated link like api